# Ubuntu not booting from usb

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

So today my hard drive on my desktop decided to fail... I am trying to launch ubuntu via USB flash drive and I am getting several errors, I used the universal USB installer to get ubuntu 12.10 desktop amd64 iso onto the usb, I prioritized it to launch from the USB and once it does I get a screen saying   *boot:*
  If I press enter the message will appear as:  *initial menu has no LABEL entries*
It then quickly disappears. I tried using Ubuntu 12.4 iso however it had a different error, where it says: 
  *unknown keyword in configuration file: niciar &
unknown keyword in configuration file: ubuntu &
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found*
  Please I have no idea what to do, I've searched but I couldn't find a solution to this problem. One result I found said: 
Open the the syslinux folder in the root of the flash drive.
Inside is a file called syslinux.cfg you’ll want to edit that.
Find the line “ui gfxboot bootlogo” and simply remove the “ui “.
Save and try booting again.
I opened the cfg file in notepad, and some spanish writing came up, I'm not sure if that is the problem... Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I managed to get ubuntu to boot from my usb flash drive by using UNetbootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ as someone suggested on this website, I had previously tried the LiLi program as well as universal usb installer but both gave me the errors I discussed above. I used the UNetbootin program and it miraculously worked, so if anyone is experiencing the errors I was getting, try out UNetbootin and hopefully it works.

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted(click on the grey tick to the left of this answer), as it seems to have solved your problem.